# How do I implement a trait on a curried function?

Tags: rust

If I try to implement the trait `Frob` for functions like `foo` as follows:

```
fn foo<'b>(state: &'b mut i32) -> impl FnMut(&str) -> i32 + 'b {
    move |i| *state
}

trait Frob<S, I, O> {
    fn frob(self, state: &mut S, input: I) -> O;
}

impl<S, I, O, F, G> Frob<S, I, O> for F
where
    F: FnMut(&mut S) -> G,
    G: FnMut(I) -> O,
{
    fn frob(mut self, state: &mut S, input: I) -> O {
        self(state)(input)
    }
}

fn bar() {
    foo.frob(&mut 1, "hi");
}
```

I get the error

```
error[E0599]: the method `frob` exists for fn item `for<'b> fn(&'b mut i32) -> impl for<'b, 'r> FnMut<(&'r str,)> {foo}`,
but its trait bounds were not satisfied
...
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `<for<'b> fn(&'b mut i32) -> impl for<'b, 'r> FnMut<(&'r str,)> {foo} as FnOnce<(&mut _,)>>::Output = _`
           which is required by `for<'b> fn(&'b mut i32) -> impl for<'b, 'r> FnMut<(&'r str,)> {foo}: Frob<_, _, _>`
           `<&for<'b> fn(&'b mut i32) -> impl for<'b, 'r> FnMut<(&'r str,)> {foo} as FnOnce<(&mut _,)>>::Output = _`
           which is required by `&for<'b> fn(&'b mut i32) -> impl for<'b, 'r> FnMut<(&'r str,)> {foo}: Frob<_, _, _>`
           `<&mut for<'b> fn(&'b mut i32) -> impl for<'b, 'r> FnMut<(&'r str,)> {foo} as FnOnce<(&mut _,)>>::Output = _`
           which is required by `&mut for<'b> fn(&'b mut i32) -> impl for<'b, 'r> FnMut<(&'r str,)> {foo}: Frob<_, _, _>`
```

First of all, how do I interpret this error message? Second, how do I write the trait bound correctly? Presumably the problem has something to do with the returned closure hanging on to `state`, but I can't find a place to specify a lifetime for `G`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. > First of all, how do I interpret this error message?

   Yes, it is a tad cryptic isn't it?  Two things to recognise:

   - `<for<'b> fn(&'b mut i32) -> impl for<'b, 'r> FnMut<(&'r str,)> {foo}` is the compiler's very wordy way of expressing the *type* of function `foo`; and
   - the same note is repeated for that function type, a shared reference to that function type, and a mutable reference to that function type—this happens when the compiler attempts automatic referencing in method call syntax such as you have in `foo.frob(...)`.

   So we can quickly distill the error message down to:

   ```
   error[E0599]: the method `frob` exists for fn item `{foo}`,
   but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   ...
      = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
              `<{foo} as FnOnce<(&mut _,)>>::Output = _`
              which is required by `{foo}: Frob<_, _, _>`
   ```

   The compiler is telling us that it found a potential `frob` method on `{foo}` but in order for it to be applicable, `{foo}`'s return type must match the constraints of the `Frob` trait (but it doesn't).
2. > Second, how do I write the trait bound correctly? Presumably the problem has something to do with the returned closure hanging on to `state`, but I can't find a place to specify a lifetime for `G`.

   You need to add the lifetime constraint to the trait ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=59901bdd4f7e99c288289aec608f9330)):

   ```
    trait Frob<'b, S, I, O> {
        fn frob(self, state: &'b mut S, input: I) -> O;
    }

    impl<'b, S: 'b, I, O, F, G> Frob<'b, S, I, O> for F
    where
        F: FnMut(&'b mut S) -> G,
        G: 'b + FnMut(I) -> O,
    {
        fn frob(mut self, state: &'b mut S, input: I) -> O {
            self(state)(input)
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: So is it not possible bound `F` as a HRTB, ie `F: for<'b> FnMut(&'b`...?

Comment: @Dan: That would require `F` to return the same `G` irrespective of the lifetime `'b`, but the closure returned by `foo` is bound by the lifetime of the borrowed `state`.